# What is the relationship between the light and dark reactions of photosynthesis?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, botany, photosynthesis, carbohydrates

My main concern is why are the dark reactions (those that produce hexose) needed? As far as I understand, the sole purpose of photosynthesis is to synthesize carbohydrates, which are only used for energy storage. So, why don’t plants store energy directly as ATP (by photophosphorylation) and not as carbohydrates? (Of course, that would be too bad for other creatures.)

Elaborating my question:

1. Plants use chlorophyll to convert light energy into chemical energy of ATP and NADPH by photophosphorylation and chemiosmosis.
2. Then plants use the ATP and NADPH to synthesize glucose by the Calvin cycle.

So, what is the need of step 2? Why don‘t plants just use that ATP and NADPH for their metabolism?

---

*PS:* although @David has provided a nice answer to the *current* form of the question, the selected answer by @christian still remains selected since it answered my *original* query i.e. *why excess ATP is not feasible for plants* instead of *why synthesis of carbohydrates is important*. Any further answers/comments shall address the latter one, although none of them can be selected as correct since the latter query is not the original one.

Comment: No, photosynthesis is used to assimilate inorganic carbon in order to use it in biosynthesis (that's what "synthesis" stands for). It has little to do with energy. There are quasiphotosyntetic bacteria that only use light to harvest energy, hence they depend on first-level producers for organic carbon (organisms with functioning Calvin cycle, Arnon cycle etc).  You need organic carbon to make proteins, nucleic acids and lipids.

Comment: thanks, i was actually misled to the fact that carbohydrates are only synthesized for energy storage, and totally forgot that all our body is carbon-based, which we basically get from carbohydrates & their derivatives ;-)

Comment: Plants are Eukaryotes and have Mitochondria, so they perform glycolysis and oxidative phosphorylation as well. Animals don't store energy in ATP any more than plants do. We store it in glycogen and fats.

Comment: Yes sir @AMR I've understood it now and thats why I've selected the answer below as correct and said thanks to Eli for the comment ;-)

Comment: Carbohydrate doesn't easily release the energy, so they can be used for storage and long-distance transport. Like a piece of paper (though cellulose), fires-up only if it gets a touch of flame, though the reaction is exothermic.

Comment: Why many biological processes are unnecessarily complicated. Anything (structure/function) found in nature, is result of accident. Nothing happened 'purposefully'. In random events of mutations etc, which one become beneficial for a certain small context; is selected.

Comment: In response to your PS. If what you say was really your intent, why pick on plants? Animals don‘t store energy as ATP either. And your original title "Why is photosynthesis so complicated?" had a focus on photosynthesis, as if you had just been introduced to the subject and could see the importance of the light reaction (perhaps considered in one chapter of a book such as Berg et al., and were puzzled about the added complexity of a separate chapter on the dark reaction, which you assumed was for storage — as you admitted in your response to @EliKorvigo.

Comment: @david you're assuming just too much. I picked plants because animals dont synthesize glucose (well, from scratch). And my question title had a focus on photosynthesis because light and dark reactions are in (quite) direct relation, but no such relation is present elsewhere (especially in animals). Again, why this question was asked is a long story that I dont wish to touch upon.

Comment: @another'Homosapien' Regarding: "animals dont synthesize glucose" –  we actually do, that's called gluconeogenesis.

Comment: @eli ah, my friend! Thats why I said "from scratch". Comments, having size limit, really aren't places for writing with proper semantics, you just have to understand some things. All right, lemme tell you the story: this account belonged to my son, he asked this (and a few more) questions. I, reluctant to make a new ID, started using his account and answering questions. He barely uses this site anymore. So, please dont think I'm a newbie ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is ATP produced in photosynthesis used to synthesize glucose?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42888/why-is-atp-produced-in-photosynthesis-used-to-synthesize-glucose) or the other way round.

Comment: @WYSIWYG this one was actually asked earlier than the other one, so... :D

Comment: @another'Homosapien' I realized after tagging. I asked the mods to merge the other question to this one, if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ATP is a bad medium for storing energy as detailed [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7234/why-can-atp-not-be-stored-in-excess).

> - ATP has a molecular weight of 507 Da
> - Glucose has a molecular weight
>     of 180 Da, and contains the same amount of energy as 31 ATP molecules

Comment: This answer addresses one aspect of the question "Why store energy as carbohydrates rather than ATP?" It could have also considered the actual storage forms (polymerized hexoses) and factors like their neutrality and osmotic properties. However, it does not dispute the assertion in the question  that the sole purpose of the synthesis of carbohydrate in the dark reaction is for storage. It is not, nor is it even the main purpose, as explained in my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Apology**

This question has a very simple answer which was provided in a comment by @EliKorvigo (and acknowledged by the poster) two years before writing this answer. However the commenter did not post an answer so the poster, instead of withdrawing his question accepted an answer that, although not factually incorrect, is not a full answer to the question. I feel that photosynthesis is an important enough topic that a more comprehensive answer should be provided.

**The Fallacy**

The poster writes in his question:

> “the sole purpose of photosynthesis is to synthesize carbohydrates,
>   which is only used *for energy storage*”

In fact, as is emphasized in [simpler accounts](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/science/add_aqa_pre_2011/plants/plants1.shtml) than [bloated biochemistry text books](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21154/),

> “the essential purpose of photosynthesis is to synthesize the
>   carbohydrates — and from them the other organic compounds — *that
>   constitute living organisms themselves* (plants and photosynthetic
>   bacteria)”

**The Purpose of the two reactions of photosynthesis**

> *Dark Reaction:* Converts CO<sub>2</sub> to carbohydrate compounds
>
> *Light Reaction:* Converts light energy to chemical energy to enable the
>   synthesis of the carbon–carbon and other bonds of the carbohydrates,
>   and the NADPH needed to reduce the CO<sub>2</sub>.

(For details *see* e.g. [Ch. 20](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21194/) and [Ch 19](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22345/), respectively of Berg et al.)

**Distribution of carbohydrate in plants and other functions**

Photosynthesis occurs in those (green) tissues of plants that contain chloroplasts. The carbohydrate product must be distributed to those other tissues that do not contain chloroplasts. This transport is done through the phloem, with the glucose 6-P and fructose 6-P first converted to the neutral transport form, sucrose. (*see* [SparkNotes](http://www.sparknotes.com/biology/plants/essentialprocesses/section2.rhtml) for a simple summary, or [Liu et al. (2012)](https://academic.oup.com/jxb/article/63/11/4315/604214) for a more advanced treatment.)

Although much of the sucrose will be metabolized to provide the structural components that constitute the tissues (especially cellulose), some of it will be used to generate the ATP and NADPH needed for metabolism.

**Storage of carbohydrates in plants**

The accepted answer can be taken as accepting the fallacy in the question that the purpose of  hexose production in photosynthesis is for storage, and further of implying that glucose is the storage form of carbohydrate in plants. Of course, polymeric hexoses, [**starch** and **sucrose**](http://lifeofplant.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/carbohydrates.html) are the main storage forms of carbohydrate in plants, together with some [fats and oils](http://www.cyberlipid.org/glycer/glyc0005.htm), especially in seeds.

Comment: It is a good answer, but I selected the earlier answer because it _was_ to the point. I do not have any problem with the modified form of the question (which, indeed, takes it to another direction) since it is also a good question for the site, but I cannot accept your answer now because it does not answer the original query (how I came to ask this question is a long story). Anyways, +1 for the effort :)

Comment: @another'Homosapien' — No problem about which answer is accepted. Just came across this question by chance and felt that an answer addressing the purpose of the dark reaction was required in addition to one dealing only with energy storage.